Vivaldi tab stack popup no longer displaying multiple columns
Up until fairly recently the popup that appears when hovering the mouse over a tab stack showed the tab thumbnails in a grid of various dimensions, depending on the number of tabs in the stack, e.g.
+---+---+
+---+---+
+---+---+
+---+---+

Now the behaviour seems to be to show all the thumbnails in a single column:
+---+
+---+
+---+
+---+
+---+
+---+
+---+

I would prefer the former behaviour. Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Vivaldi changed this in one of the versions. Only way to get it back is by uninstalling Vivaldi, and installing an older version again where that behavior was not yet possible. Alternatively, do a feature request, and request it back as optional feature.

Vivaldi actually listens to its users. Check out their forum. A number of us were upset that a recent update moved the New Tab button to a different spot when tabs were on the left. They actually reversed the change, apparently in response to our complaints.

This was a regression which was fixed in Vivaldi 6.9.
